# Why does adding a CSS link to my jade template make my node app crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

Not sure what's going on here. I've done this kind of thing before and it's worked fine. I'm trying to make a blog that loads posts in markdown format from MongoDB and inserts them into a jade template. That part all seems to work fine, until I try to add a CSS file (I'm using `app.use(express.static(dirname__ + '/public'))` and putting the CSS file in `public`). Before adding the link to the CSS file into the Jade file, everything works fine. When I add a link to the CSS file though, the app loads correctly, but without the CSS styles added, and an error message appears in the terminal. Then of course if I try to refresh, it tells me the webpage is not available.

Here's the error message it gives me:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined
```

Here's the router that the error message points to:

```
app.get('/article/:title', function(req, res){
    var title = req.params.title;
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }else{
            var col = db.collection('posts');
            col.find({ title: title }).toArray(function(err, docs){
                if(err){
                    return err;
                }else{
                    res.render('article', { md: marked, post: docs[0].entry })
                    return db.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here's my jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
        title Article
    body
        header
            h1 Blog Title
                br
                span Subheader
        content!= md(post)
```

I've tried several different things. It seems that pointing the link to a nonexistent file has no effect at all, so the problem isn't with the integrity of the CSS link, but with the act of linking to it. I've also compared this with other node apps I've made like this that do work, and I don't see any significant difference. And again, there's no error with the app until I try adding the link to the CSS file into the jade template. It loads everything(including the markdown from the database, and renders it on the page), but doesn't include the CSS styles, then it crashes. Can someone give me an idea as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
link(href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

and put your css in the stylesheets folder

Comment: That worked... but now I'm super confused, because every other project I've made, I didn't add slashes, but they still worked. Do you know if there's a reason they're necessary sometimes, but sometimes not?